# The "f" suffix in floating point numbers

Tags: c

I know that similar questions are already posted many times here and I searched with Google and here and read answers to those questions, but there is something not clear to me and here it is:

```
float x = 1.5; 
float z = 0.0;
z = x + 5.22f;
```

Here I am convinced that it is necessary to add `f` after the number 5.22 so that the compiler won't treat it as `double`.

The point is in the book I am reading the author do this:

```
float myvar = 2.55f;
```

My question is: I already declared "myvar" to be `float` what is the purpose of the `f` suffix? Why the repetition?

Is it possible that the compiler treats the value 2.55 as a `double` and when it tries to assign it to `myvar` it demotes it to `float`, so the purpose of the `f` is to prevent this?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary.  The author may be being overly prudent.

Comment: @shree.pat18 , thank you , i didn't get this post when i searched . it has the answer to my question , thank you

Comment: @Jim , thank you for replaying , i found this in the "@see.pat18" link , it says : float x = 0.0 has an implicit typecast from double to float.

Depending on the compiler, implicit typecast can require the compiler to generate extra code.

Comment: Your compiler may emit a warning for assigning a double to a float. The f suffix forces the constant to be a float, thereby avoiding the warning.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thank you sir , i will check the  warning lever in my compiler ,thank you very  much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unadorned floating point constants are `double` values.  Therefore, in:

```
float x = 1.5;
```

the `1.5` is a `double` value.  Now, in this context, even the most dim-witted compiler is going to generate the same code as it would if you wrote:

```
float x = 1.5f;
```

So in this context, it doesn't matter.  When does it matter?  When you use the constant in a calculation:

```
float y = x * 2.3;
```

The multiplication is done using `double` and then the result converted to `float`, compared with:

```
float z = x * 2.3f;
```

where the multiplication is done using `float`.  In pre-standard C, all floating point computations were done in `double`, so the distinction didn't matter, but all versions of Standard C allow the computation for all operands `float` to be done in `float`.

Comment: thank you sir, that was the answer i was hoping for , very clear, thanks